# Is it possible to create a USB Bootable version of Ubuntu with Persistent Storage?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I saw [this link](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB) on how to create a version of Fedora that can boot directly from a USB stick and have persistent storage as large as the stick itself.

I tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) to no avail. I have also read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) but I am still unclear:

I am wondering if there is an official way to do this?  Can someone describe a method or point me to the direction of the best way to make a usb-bootable version of Ubuntu with more than 4GB of storage?

NOTE: I am interested in any solutions but *preferably* this would work cross platform.

Comment: @karel, yep, I read that (see linked to in my answer) however that didn't work. I am trying to see if that is still the best way to do it or if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home to create a usb bootable with persistent storage.

Check the Help to have more than 4Gb : http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/persistence and this link http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/

Comment: For cross platform https://unetbootin.github.io/ can replace linux live usb. (seems persistent storage works only for ubuntu live usb)