# Code::Blocks on LiveUSB

Tags: live-usb

My problem is that on my workstation there is no internet so I cannot download code::blocks directly onto computer(I do not have root accessw as well).I decided to prepare Ubuntu on my USB and install code::blocks there,but when I plug out my USB and then plug there is no code::blocks on LiveUSB.How can I solve it?

Comment: You need a persistent Live USB, to save changes between sessions, are you making it in Ubuntu or windows ?

Comment: Code::Blocks needs to be installed each time the USB is inserted, as LiveUSB systems do not keep changes, they are fixed in a ghost filesystem. You would have to set-up persistence on your live USB or create your own custom LiveUSB image of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm making it on Kubuntu.

Comment: Refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb). Then simply boot your persistent live USB and install Code::Blocks with `sudo apt-get install codeblocks`.

Comment: @hg8 I say that but it does not address the issue all it says for creating a persistence file is "Install Ubuntu live on 2 USB drives. Configure a small persistent storage of around 100 MB for each of the USB drives" It tries to by pass a 4gb limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `persistence file` on the USB to do this in `startup-disk-creator`, set it up as normal and then make sure to check `stored in reserved extra space` and set the storage amount (1GB min) under `when starting up from disk......`

[image]

Comment: Yes I installed it but when I did it in home and then plugged in the USB to computer in my work, there was no code::blocks.

Comment: See my new answer :)