# xubuntu persistent live usb

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, persistence

I have been attempting to create a Xubuntu live USB using using these instructions for quite a few hours:[How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb). I followed the instructions to the letter and now my usb crashes on bootup. I repeated the instructions a few times and checked everything but it still will not work. Please help.

Comment: what "does not work"?

Comment: Which verison of Xubuntu? I have got 16.04 to work, but so far nothing I have tried has resulted in a bootable 16.10 usb: usb-creator-gtk has hidden the persistence button, Unetbootin claims to create a bootable USB but fails to mount /cow, and mkusb fails to boot at all, claiming a missing kernel.

Comment: Note that installing to the USB key as if were a normal harddisk still works, and results in a kind of persistent USB key: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Use mkusb - it works. Read the instructions from Harsh:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? The linked question has multiple answers. You can link directly to answers via the ”share” link below them. What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do this via mkusb tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent
This will do the job automatically.
First check if the usb drive is ok and non damaged.