# Transfer files from casper-rw to a fresh install

Tags: dual-boot, usb, live-usb

So I have been booting from a live usb with casper-rw, to store programs and whatnot on.  After running out of space on the casper-rw file, I decided to install Ubuntu from the live usb stick....So I am currently dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7

I kind of hoped that this would just grab all of the stuff from the casper-rw file (documents, programs, etc.), but it did not.

So the question is, how do I get all of the stuff from the casper-rw file of the Usb drive, without destroying everything (I would prefer windows stay intact, but have made a backup just in case)

Answer (score 2):

Well, to transfer files you can mount the Ubuntu root partition (or `/home` if it is on a separate partition) and just copy the files you can access on your USB that way.

Let's say you have a directory on your USB called Documents that you want to copy to your installed Ubuntu's home directory. You could do this...

First, from your full installation, find out what your root partition is on your installation by doing

```
lsblk
```

Take note of the partition mounted on `/` (or `/home` if it's separate)

Now boot the live usb and mount that partition. Replace `/dev/sdxY` with the correct partition name

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxY /mnt
```

Now your home directory is located at /mnt/home/username so you can do (replace with your real username)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/home/username/casperdocs
sudo cp -r Documents /mnt/home/username/casperdocs
```

to copy the Documents directory to `~/casperdocs` on your installation

Very important - don't forget to unmount the partition when you are done:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxY
```

now reboot into your installation and you will find the files.

With programs (assuming you mean repository packages) you should install through `apt` rather than trying to copy their files this way.

Answer (score 2):

`casper-rw` is a file with an `ext4` filesystem within it. So, you can just mount it and copy the contents from it in your Regular Ubuntu installation.

Assuming you're in a location where `casper-rw` file resides, you can mount it at `/mnt` using command

```
sudo mount ./casper-rw /mnt
```

Then the whole directory tree of an Ubuntu system will appear in `/mnt` directory. These are the files *newly created* on Live system, or *modified*.

*Note for 16.04:* However, in 16.04 Ubuntu's **Startup disk creator** is [missing option for using a persistence file](https://askubuntu.com/a/772100/61218) like `casper-rw`. It uses `dd` instead. In that case, you might be using tools like `mkusb`. If you're using `mkusb`, it won't create a file, instead create a separate partition in your USB. It will named as `casper-rw`. If you access those files without using mount command, from Files.

Here is a list of interesting files you might want to copy:

1. Your downloaded/created documents will be in `/mnt/home`. You can copy and paste them one by one in your Ubuntu home `/home`. But if you want to copy all of them once (which could go wrong sometimes) you can quickly run

   ```
   cp -r -p -u /mnt/home/ubuntu/ /home/rubik/ -v
   ```

   Here,

   - `-r` is for recursively copying the files from Live system to your home
   - `-p` is for preserving the permission. I'm assuming that you're the first created user, so your UID is 1000 which will match the UID of the LIVE system user `ubuntu`.
   - `-u` is update only. That means, if you already have a file in your new Ubuntu installation which is of same name but new, it will not be replaced by the one from older Live system.
   - Also I'm assuming that your user name is `rubik`. If it is not, replace it with the actual one.
2. The downloaded packages are in `/mnt/var/cache/apt/archives` folder. You can copy them somewhere else and quickly run a `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install all of them again.
3. Other configuration files will be in `/mnt/etc/` directory just like regular Ubuntu installation. If you added PPAs, those PPAs sources will be found in `/mnt/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. You can copy them to your main Ubuntu. Don't forget to copy the associated key from `/mnt/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`.

Hope this will help you regain your files from `casper-rw`.

Comment: Oh that's the proper answer, nice :)

Comment: Your answer will work too! If OP wants only the files in Home directory. Thanks