# No idea how to install newer version of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, bios

I have Ubuntu 14.04 but I want to install 16.04. I have downloaded the ISO file and then used the program "Startup Disk Creator" that comes with Ubuntu to create a startup disk using my USB drive.

I then restarted the computer and entered BIOS and set the configurations so it starts from my pendrive instead of the HDD. It then takes me to a screen where the following message repeats ad infinitum "COM32R is not a readable file" or something to that effect.

I have been told that a fresh install is better than updating Ubuntu which is why I am doing it this way but I am fast running out of patience. Please help.

Comment: You should be able to run `do-release-upgrade` from a terminal window to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: Hi Terrance. Thanks for your reply. My understanding is that this would just upgrade the version I have now and I want to do a fresh install. Can you confirm if this is correct or not please?

Comment: Yes, it would only upgrade.  If your 14.04 LTS is working good, you can do just the upgrade with no external media required.  But if you want to do a fresh install, then yes, you need to create some sort of bootable media for 16.04.  I do not recommend using the USB Creator as it does not seem to work well anymore since they made some changes to it.  Try maybe using some from this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/841843/what-program-to-use-when-you-want-to-create-a-persistent-storage-live-usb-in-ubu/842844#842844

Comment: Well, the Live-USB--Install program used in the link you have just given me also doesn't work. It says if I download it that I may have serious problems with my computer as it does not meet quality standards. Canonical really don't like people using their products it seems.......

Comment: That link does work.  No need to donate, just have them show you, or here's the direct download of that same file:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/liveusbinstall/files/live-usb-install-2.5.11-all.deb/download

Comment: Thanks again Terrance. This must be testing your patience now too. I had already downloaded the install file but when I click on it once it downloads to my desktop, it takes me to a page on the Ubuntu Software Centre to install the program and this is where it says that the program could damage my computer.

Comment: That is a normal warning that you get from any software that is not controlled by them.  It can still be installed.  Easiest actually to install the application from a terminal window through the instructions on the answer I wrote there.

Comment: By the way, I never write an answer of something that I have not tested myself.

Comment: I've almost always seen better luck when using a DVD. If you have a DVD drive, you might want to consider burning the ISO.