# Startup Disk Creator wants to wipe drive?

Tags: startup-disk-creator

Today I went to write an 18.04 ISO onto a USB drive from my 16.04 installation, and Startup Disk Creator wanted to wipe the entire drive:

[image]

Now, perhaps my memory is incorrect, but I seem to recall that when I was on 14.04, Statup Disk Creator worked without needing to wipe the entire drive.

Has the behavior of Startup Disk Creator been changed since 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The option to NOT erase the USB was dropped in between Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

According to the accepted answer to [Where is the persistent option for Startup Disk Creator in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772093/where-is-the-persistent-option-for-startup-disk-creator-in-16-04) the underlying process used by the **Startup Disk Creator** changed in Ubuntu 16.04. The newer version of this app uses the `dd` command line utility in the background.

As a result of this change the USB drive is wiped clean when it is used to make a startup disk. The new background process also does not allow for creating persistent Live USB.

Hope this helps

Comment: So here's a related question.... if Startup Disk Creator just uses `dd` now, what's the beneifit of using it over just doing `dd if=someImage.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M`?

Comment: Apparently there is no difference other than the nice graphical user interface.