# Mac bootable live USB with over 4gb persistence

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mac, persistence

I'm trying to create a live USB that is bootable on Mac and has over 4gb of persistent storage. I've used the [Mac Bootable USB Loader](https://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/) to make it Mac bootable, which works. I've attempted to follow the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) to create a `casper-rw` partition in GParted using a second Ubuntu USB.

When I boot my USB, I have only 1.9gb available, not the 100+ I should have. If I open GParted, I have only 1 partition, exactly as if I hadn't even created the `casper-rw` partition in the first place.

The directions are very easy to follow. I did get a warning about using FAT32 instead of FAT16 (something about having to reinstall the boot loader if I was using Windows), but I don't think that is the issue.

Why isn't my drive partitioning properly? Do these instructions just not work for Mac-bootable USBs?

Comment: How is this an Ubuntu question?

Comment: @ThomasW. Am I wrong in assuming that this forum is for Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based distros (like Mint)? Feel free to remove this question if I am. In any case,  this info could be useful for someone looking to create a persistent Mac bootable Ubuntu USB, not just Mint. One of the problems I ran into was specifically because I was using Ubuntu as part of this process. I feel it's valid.

Comment: Mint is not an official derivative of Ubuntu and we only provide support for the official flavors of Ubuntu - not Mint and others that are derived from Ubuntu (as they are not an official flavor or variant).  Go read the help center for details on what is on topic here

Comment: @ThomasW. Ah. Gotcha. Should I just delete the question, or leave it for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue occurred due to a bug in the version of GParted included with Ubuntu 14.04, which I has been using to edit my partitions. Basically, it crashed when I tried to resize a FAT32 partition. To solve this, I remade my secondary live USB with Ubuntu 12.04 to use a non-broken version of GParted.

(Because I ran in to unrelated issues later, I ended up following [these](https://usbubuntu.wordpress.com) instructions, with some tweaking.)