# Ubuntu 14.0.4 persistent in files but not programs

Tags: persistence

32GB sandisk 3.0 USB
Ubuntu 14.0.4
"persistence" partition operating and saving any fields downloaded to /home/ubuntu/Downloads then moved to /media/ubuntu/persistence

persistence was built as per USB Installer commands.

nothing on the main /home/ubuntu destination seems to save, not even wireless network passwords.

What am I missing?
I fully downloaded and installed teamviewer, ran it, then shutdown and tested persistence. 
Nothing was saved other than the 
teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb file

Comment: And also some more information is needed. Like how did you set it up for persistence?

Comment: @Android Dev the partition I created was to be called "persistence" here is the commands followed. it seems as though only that partition is persistent, but not the entire USB as it should be. Nothing saves unless I transfer the files to the partition I created. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb