# Creating casper-rw partition causing Lubuntu Live USB not to boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, lubuntu, live-usb, persistence

I have found recently that setting up a Live USB with Lubuntu 16.04.1 and a persistent partition using the process described in the top answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) causes the Live USB to be unable to boot. The screen instead is blank with a blinking cursor. Has the process for creating a persistent Live USB changed since the last time I was able to get this to work in 13.10 (14.04 - 16.04 seemed to suffer from [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855))? Is there any way to fix this so that I can have persistence over 4 GB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest solution for you is to install ***mkusb*** and let it start from the beginning. It creates a **casper-rw partition** for persistence automatically.

You can decide how much of the available drive space to use for persistence. The rest (of the available drive space) will be used for a **usbdata** partition, available also from Windows.

See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)