# Over 4GB Persistence on LiveUSB Boot drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, persistence

I want to create a USB drive with Linux on it and some games installed. I have figured out it's pretty hard. I have been doing different stuff for a lot of hours already and never really got it working.

So the USB drive I have is 64GB and I'd like to have Ubuntu on it and the rest would be for having games installed that I can run on a computer in school etc.. I have tried following the instructions given here: [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) but I haven't gotten it working. I need something simple and pretty step-by-step instructions because I've tried a lot of things for literally 10 hours and haven't gotten it working.

Comment: Why not just put a regular installation of Ubuntu on the 64G drive, with a FAT32 partition for shared data with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use the application [`Universal USB Installer`.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) It is really easy and straight forward for usage. You can set the persistence to a value even higher than 4GB. When you have Ubuntu (or whatever linux distro) installed on it, just simply re-mount the drive (plug it out and plug it in again).

Then copy what ever games you want to the drive. You will be able to run the games from the usb drive and it will still be bootable.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this (get the value higher that 4GB) and I don't think your plan would've worked