# How to install ubuntu mini.iso?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install ubuntu mini 18.04 from a booted DVD . 
I connected my laptop to the LAN of my college .
I restart my laptop and select 'install ubuntu' to install but it is not connecting/detecting my LAN cabel network .
What's the problem, i am not able to install Ubuntu mini .

Comment: Which hardware do you have? Is there a specific reason for using the mini image, and not normal installer?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106829/install-lubuntu-18-10-on-a-4gb-virtual-machine) might help

Comment: _I want to install ubuntu mini because i want to install desktop environment manually, i am curretly using ubuntu 18.04 and i am now at college, so i am texting you with the same laptop and same network in which i want to install ._

Comment: _@Kulfy.. I don't want virtual box ._

Comment: _I can connect to the internet through that LAN, but when I used to install ubuntu mini, that LAN not working ._

Answer (score 0):

Install mini system, then you`ll be able to install full desktop. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

> The minimal iso image will download packages from online archives at
>   installation time instead of providing them on the install media
>   itself. Downloading packages at install time reduces the size of the
>   iso image to approximately ~40MB depending on architecture (see
>   below), as well as providing only the packages needed for
>   installation.

Mini requires internet connection. I don't remember exactly will mini provide text interface to install desktop or not, anyway you can always do it from command line, like:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop`.

**If you don't have internet connection with mini, its not your option to install, use full dvd.**

> While the minimal iso image is handy, it isn't useful for installing
>   on UEFI-based systems that you want to run in UEFI mode. The mini iso
>   lacks the proper files for booting the computer in UEFI mode. Thus,
>   the computer will boot in BIOS compatibility mode, and the
>   installation will be in BIOS mode.
>
> You can use an Ubuntu Server amd64 iso file (64-bit) for 'mini
>   installations' in UEFI mode.

Try server image.

Comment: _Is there any way to install mini ISO through a WI-FI ?_

Comment: No there is not.