# Installing Lubuntu 18.10 on usb flash drive with 7.2gb storage

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I can't install lubuntu from a live usb to the same usb drive. The installation won't proceed because

> "There is not enough drive space. At least 8GB is required."

Is there are workaround to this?

Comment: Can you use 2 USBs?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Nope, only a couple of Sd cards

Comment: As long as 7.2GB is less than 8GB, no. Further, installing over the system you're booting from is not possible.

Comment: @waltinator I've read that creating a partition on the same usb drive would work. The only problem is storage space. Live lubuntu takes up no more than 2gb, i don't understand why a full installation would need 8gb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Lubuntu 18.10 on a 4GB Virtual Machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106829/install-lubuntu-18-10-on-a-4gb-virtual-machine)

Comment: You can start the installer with a bigger disk through a usb adapter and then swap the disk with the proper one.
To find the correct disk, select manual formatting and use the revert button!