# Unable to get persistent partition to work with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: live-usb, 17.04, mkusb

I made a live USB for Ubuntu 17.04 using MKUSB from this tutorial here: [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb)

But I am unable to get the persistent storage to work for me. The live USB has been created successfully and it boots perfectly fine but it looses all my files on reboot.

I tried adding the word "persistent" to every line with "linux" in the boot.cfg and loopback.cfg files.

**Edit**: I used a 16GB USB to make the Live USB. Though I found out one thing, if while booting I edit the boot commands from grub to add a 'persistent' keyword, persistence works just fine. If I do not, it doesn't. Hence I have to manually edit the command everytime I have to boot into Ubuntu Live.

Here's what my loopback.cfg file looks like before I edit for persistence.

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash persistent --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash persistent --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Test memory" {
    linux16 /install/mt86plus
}
```

Here's what I edit to make persistence work.

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash persistent --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash persistent --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash persistent --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Test memory" {
    linux16 /install/mt86plus
}
```

I have to manually edit it everytime I boot because the changes I make to the file from Windows revert back to original.

Comment: how big is the USB? could you actually install a minimal ubuntu to it insted of the live image?

Comment: I will try to help you :-) But I need more information about what you have and what you did. 1) Which of the answers in that thread did you use?; 2) Please describe the computer (at least brand name and model); 3) Please edit your original question and add the output of the following command lines, when booted from the live drive, `df -h` ; `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` ;  `uname -a` ; `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I used a 16GB USB to make the Live USB.
Though I found out one thing, if while booting I edit the boot commands from grub to add a 'persistent' keyword, persistence works just fine. If I do not, it doesn't.
Hence I have to manually edit the command everytime I have to boot into Ubuntu Live.