# Losing my files when I restart my PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu

I installed KUbuntu 16.04.3 LTS in a flash drive and successfully booted to them from my Windows 10 PC . However , every file I make is lost when I restart my PC.

I think i have found the answer I'm looking for in another thread : I have created a live CD/usb that is only used to "try" ubuntu before installing them for real in a hard drive.

So the real question(s) is(are) :

a) is what i just wrote true

b) if it is , can i somehow install ubuntu to my flash drive ? If not , can i save files on my flash drive so I can access them when I restart my PC and boot to kubuntu ?

Kinda unrelated , but if b) isn't true :

I have an 1TB HDD hard drive and an 120GB SSD (the ssd has win10 installed) on in my pc. If I split my HDD to 900GB -124GB and use the 124gb partition to install kubuntu there , will I have to choose what OS I want to boot into every time I start my PC or can I make win10 the default and have to go to the bios every time i want to boot to kubuntu ?

The reason I ask this is because I dont wont to lose the "pc starts in 4 seconds" bonus from having a ssd :(

Comment: You might want to create a [persistent live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb).

Comment: But since I'm here you can install ubuntu onto a flash drive if you have a second drive and choose to install onto that drive instead of your hard drive

Comment: You haven't installed it on your USB. You have made a bootable USB with which either you can install or try ubuntu. I you really need to have Ubuntu only on USB and keep your changes perminant, try the solution provided by friends to make persistent live USB

Answer (score 1):

There is a method of installing Ubuntu to run "persistently" from your Flash drive, but I would recommend against it for any routine use.  Thumb drive Flash RAM wears out much more quickly than SSDs, and the wearout is far less predictable.  You'll be running happily on your USB stick, and the next time you want to start, it won't, because too many cells have gone bad for the thumb drive's balancing system to work around -- and there's no warning this is about to happen.

Your SSD is faster than any thumb drive (even a top-end, USB 3.0 version is limited by the USB transfer speed, which is less than that of the current version SATA interface).  Therefore, the best way to preserve the rapid starting of your computer is to install to your SSD in a dual- or multi-boot setup.  You'll spend several seconds in GRUB, but from there, you'll get the fastest start your hardware is capable of.