# How to Create Persistent USB Key with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, 17.10

I use linux Ubuntu via a 32GB USB. Everytime I boot it, it doesn't save my data. Therefore, I found that I can create a live persistence key which I did with the help of this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ 
Which I did but doesn't save my data.
Notes: I dont want to install linux on my computer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you saying those Windows instructions are wrong? Or are you asking us which step you apparently didn't follow? I'm not sure I see how this is an Ubuntu question. It seems like a Windows question.

Comment: This question appearers to already have an answer at [how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb)

Comment: If you are making the USB in Windows try Universal https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ If you are making it in Ubuntu use mkusb https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb both make bootable Linux USB's with unlimited persistence.

Answer (score 1):

- In **Ubuntu**, Debian and many but not all 're-spins' [operating systems] based on them, you can install **mkusb** and create a persistent live drive according to the following links,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)
- In **Windows**, you can install and use

  - [**Rufus**](https://rufus.ie), an extracting tool, which is easy to use.
  - **Win32 Disk Imager**, a cloning tool, and clone an image file with [a persistent live operating system and] mkusb. See the following links,

    [wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD)

    [Compressed image file with a persistent live system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Compressed_image_file_with_a_persistent_live_system)
- In most operating systems (including **MacOS**), you can also try with **Unetbootin** according to the following link,

  [unetbootin.github.io/](http://unetbootin.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide/preparation)(LinuxLiveUsb). This application allows creation of a live disk with persistence.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Universal USB Installer for years and never had a problem with persistence.
https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
as a side note the multiboot tool is also fantastic at creating a boot disk that contains as many live environments as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ventoy`. As per their [website](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) it is opensource and you can boot multiple OS live image ISO image from single USB.

Copy Ubuntu ISO image on `ventoy` USB disk and boot in to live disk. From here you can install Ubuntu on a UBS disk which will be a persistent one.