# Unable to update kernel (or anything), dpkg returns error 1

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dpkg

running a brand new install, just upgraded, and I hit these errors.

Running apt-get upgrade says kernel has unmet dependencies, suggests apt-get -f install, running that returns dpkg error 1. Tried searching everything, can't find solution.

Running dpkg --configure -a returns same kernel dependency errors.

Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.03 LTS.

```
user@user:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
user@user:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ys
(Reading database ... 191549 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to sync file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic.dpkg-new': Input/output error
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
user@user:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic is not installed.
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.13.0.32.52); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
user@user:~$
```

Comment: Copy the exact commands you used into the post above,also include the error text. Type `<pre>` on the line before what you include, and `</pre>` on the line just after it.

Comment: says too many characters for this comment. I'll try to break it up. N/M, added to OP.

Comment: Please execute `df -h` and include the output of that command in your question

Comment: `unable to sync file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic.dpkg-new': Input/output error`: That's a problem. Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive. dpkg error 1 simply means that some subordinate script had a failure.

Comment: re: "dh -f", don't have it installed, when I try to install it, I'm back to same problem. Re: input/output error: This is on a pretty new USB, I'll check it out.

Comment: No problems with the USB. Still not sure...

Comment: Did you try "sudo apt install --fix-missing"?

Comment: Rather than `df -h` as @CharlesGreen suggests, try `du -h` which does pretty much the same thing and is installed by default: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410997/whats-the-difference-between-du-and-df

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix .. `du -h` does not do pretty much the same as `df -h` The last show mountet filesystems and their usage, where as du -h shows the size of directories in the current working directory .. far from the same. Also `df` ìs istalled as standard too.

Comment: @SorenA OP says `df` isn't installed... Anyway is OP trying to upgrade a USB with live persistence? If so it doesn't work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986622/ubuntu-16-04-persistent-live-usb-stick-error-when-upgrading

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Op accidently tried to run `dh -f` - a small typo...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes I repeated OP's typo, which led me to `du -h` which I suggested in order to get size of `/boot` which could then later be compared to `lsblk` which I thought was the end goal. Thanks for clearing the muddy waters :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ayuh - I had suspected a disk full as well, although there is no evidence of that.  I would suggest that the OP run the SMART tests as suggested by user535733, or open '/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb' using the file archiver to check for a corrupt archive.

Comment: @CharlesGreen OP says: *" I'm back to same problem. Re: input/output error: This is on a pretty new USB, I'll check it out"*. This implies to me Ubuntu is installed to a USB with live persistence which means it can't be upgraded as per my earlier link in comments.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Good catch on the USB comment - I had not noticed that.  I can't find much info on using USB as the 'main drive' although I know that it's considered 'possible'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/) and [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/)