# How to convert an usb iso9660 filesystem to ext4

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu

I have created a Kubuntu bootable stick on sdb but did not create a separate /home.  Now I want a separate /home.  I open gparted from an Ubuntu installed on sdaX but filesystem is shown as iso9660 with no options to resize or convert to ext4.  How would I create a new /home partition from an iso9660?  I've seen other posts that describe how to do it from and ext4 filesystem but none from a iso9660.

Comment: There's no Easy Way to do this. It will be less stressful to re-create your Kubuntu USB with "persistent storage". See http://hannahnapier.co.uk/2011/01/persistent-kubuntu-usb/ if you're on Windows, or https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you.  Funny thing is I look at sdb1 (usb drive) in gparted running Ubuntu and it shows iso9660 type file system .  I recall installing it as ext4 and using Kubuntu system installer from a live DVD it shows ext4.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mvxdogwdgw8u4a/Gparted.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Here is what KED Partion manage shows...https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dd449fh11p45i8/KDEPartMgr.jpeg?dl=0