# Persistence on live pendrive

Tags: live-usb

Been thwarted at getting "persistence" on a Xubuntu live pendrive.

I tried a couple of different methods, but neither worked. So, looking for anybody experienced in doing this. Here are the 2 methods that failed:

1. [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/q/397481/681688), wouldn't boot up after executing said operations.
2. [rufus-win8ee-lm171c-uefi-mk-a-persistent-live-flashdrive](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/583139/rufus-win8ee-lm171c-uefi-mk-a-persistent-live-flashdrive/); on this operation, #27 returned "no such file or directory".

I could provide more details, but it would be a lengthy essay. This is the specs: Xubuntu 17.10 & 18.04 (tried both)-Lexar 16GB 3.0 pendrive- Dell 7040/7090 Optiplex. Oh, for some reason Unetbootin, Pendrivelinux nor LiLi will work but Rufus does (to make a bootable stick).(???)

Comment: Checksum your iso and follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: Try YUMI if on Windows or mkusb if on Linux. for large persistence.

Comment: In Ubuntu or a community flavour of Ubuntu: Try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It works with all current versions and flavours of Ubuntu (including Xubuntu) to make a persistent live drive. In Windows: [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) works for me. See more details in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10).