# Installing ubuntu 16.04 on a usb flash drive using windows

Tags: 16.04

So i installed ubuntu on a flash drive using rufus, but every time i reboot everything gets erased (everything i did in the last session before rebooting.)

Comment: oh btw i'm going by this tutorial:   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: This might help. https://askubuntu.com/a/438734/816190

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. You're making an 'live' flash drive. It behaves like a cd/dvd. Changes aren't stored on the drive.

You need to create a drive with persistence. I use Unetbootin for that task: https://unetbootin.github.io/

1. Download the program, install it and launch it.
2. Choose a distribution from the list *or* choose the diskimage you've already downloaded.
3. Set 'space used to preserve files across reboots' to any other value than 0 MB.

Another option is to use 2 flash drives: first launch the live version of Ubuntu from a drive and start the installer. Install Ubuntu on the second disk, make sure the boot loader is also installed on the second flash drive. Turn off your computer when the install is completed. Remove the first drive and reboot your computer. All changes you make on the second drive are now saved. Make sure you use a fast flash drive with enough space.

By the way, you can also use a SD card (that's what I did a while ago to dual boot macOS and Ubuntu).

Comment: However, you can click on the checkmark at left to show the answer worked for you, which helps others see a _successful_ solution to your issue exists.

Comment: huh, well i still have a problem, it still doesn't save. When i enter the bios, it gives me the option to try ubuntu or install it. I want to keep it on my flash drive, so i still have a problem. (it asks me to try or install it every time i reboot)