# password change won't stick for mkusb default user `ubuntu`

Tags: login, live-usb, password, persistence, mkusb

I recently used Harsh's [mkusb instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) to create a persistent live USB. The default user for this live USB is named `ubuntu` with a default password  of blank. I try to change user `ubuntu`'s password via:

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

Then I enter the new password. The next time I reboot the live USB system the password defualts back to  blank. The password I entered during `sudo passwd ubuntu` gets lost to the ether.

What happened to my password and how do I get it to remain permanent for this persistent live USB?

Comment: Creating a new user works for me.

Comment: With 18.04 default user is "Live session user" not "ubuntu" and password can not be changed. Using Settings/Details/Users/ you can add user Full Name "ubuntu", Username "ubuntu1" and use any password nine or more digits long. The name ubuntu will then be used when logging in and the password will stick. The user "Live session user" can then be removed.

Comment: You can create *any* new user ID and name, and that new user can and should get a password as described at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111983/password-for-live-usb-with-persistence/1112626#1112626). The Ubuntu persistent live system 'does not want' to change the password of the default user, but that user can be removed after you have created another user with a password and admin privileges.