# When I am trying Ubuntu from a USB drive, can I save my work?

Tags: live-usb

When I am trying Ubuntu from an USB drive, can I save my work? Is it possible to keep installed software and configs for the next session?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Comment: Thank you very much, the DUS is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Do NOT spend a big ammount of time using the live USB in the hopes of preserving what you have, the liveCD is using RAM as it's storage space (obviously, since it does not have your explicit permission to start using your hard drives) and as we know RAM is cleared on every reboot or as soon as there no longer is any more power (poweroff).

you could look into [making persistent live CDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb).

but to me the point of that is moot. You are much better off simply installing ubuntu to one of your drives.